# How to utilize if else in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries :

```py
data = [{'end_time': 1628565660, 'show': 'mad.men', 'cost': 0.0023123688 }, 
    {'end_time': 1628565780, 'show': 'the.sopranos', 'cost': 0.0023123688},
    {'end_time': 1628565780, 'show': 'breaking.bad', 'cost': 1.0667859907}]
```

Here I have a list of nested dictionaries :

```
[{'mad.men': {'timestamp': '1628566560', 'cost': 0}, 
  'breaking.bad': {'timestamp': '1628566560', 'cost': 0}, 
  'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566560', 'cost': 0}}, 
 {'mad.men': {'timestamp': '1628566620', 'cost': 0}, 
  'breaking.bad': {'timestamp': '1628566620', 'cost': 0}, 
  'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566620', 'cost': 0}}, 
 {'mad.men': {'timestamp': '1628566680', 'cost': 0}, 
  'breaking.bad': {'timestamp': '1628566680', 'cost': 0}, 
  'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566680', 'cost': 0}}, 
 {'mad.men': {'timestamp': '1628566740', 'cost': 0}, 
  'breaking.bad': {'timestamp': '1628566740', 'cost': 0}, 
  'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566740', 'cost': 0}}, 
 {'mad.men': {'timestamp': '1628566800', 'cost': 0}, 
  'breaking.bad': {'timestamp': '1628566800', 'cost': 0}, 
  'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566800', 'cost': 0}}, 
 {'mad.men': {'timestamp': '1628566860', 'cost': 0}, 
  'breaking.bad': {'timestamp': '1628566860', 'cost': 0}, 
  'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566860', 'cost': 0}}]
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to iterate through my `data` list and `results` list   match the show and the timestamp so I can replace the cost  within that timestamp with the data that just came in .

For example if data has   :
`'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566860', 'cost': 5.00`
and the list of results matches with the the timestamp , this value in results:

```
'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566560', 'cost': 0}
```

converts into

```
'the.sopranos': {'timestamp': '1628566560', 'cost': 5.00}
```

this is what I have attempted so far :

```
for item in data:
dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item['end_time'] / 1000.0).replace(second=0, microsecond=0).strftime('%s')
for k, v in [(k, v)  for x in results for (k, v) in x.items() if  k == item['show'] and  dt_object == v['timestamp']]:
    print(k,v)
```

but it only prints nothing.How can I achieve an if – else like this in a list comprehension? or rather another option to my problem

Comment: I'd just like to say that, when your list comprehensions become larger than a certain size, you're probably better off just using a loop solution. This may be one of those cases. The great power of list comprehensions is their expressiveness (functionality combined with succinctness). When the succinctness disappears, expressiveness is degraded: `[a+b*c for a in fn(x) if condition(a) else 42 for b i range(15) if a+b <22 else 13 for c in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11) if a + b ==c]` is *not* something I'd ever want to see in the field :-) Even it it's valid, which it may not be :-)

Comment: Do you want to update all of "the.sopranos", or only one of them? And if so, which one? `'end_time': 162856 5780` in particular happens before all of the timestamps in the long list (where the earliest one is `162856 6560`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use list comprehension in this case, but rather a for loop.

```
for item in data:
    show = item['show']
    timestamp = item['end_time']
    cost = item['cost']
    for result in results:
        info = result[show]
        if info['timestamp'] != timestamp:
            continue
        result['cost'] = cost
print(results)
```

or if you want a shorter version:

```
for item in data:
    for result in results:
        info = result[item['show']]
        if info['timestamp'] != item['end_time']:
            continue
        result['cost'] = item['cost']
print(results)
```

From the info you provided, there is no match in the timeout in the `data` with the `results`

Comment: thank you for responding , I have tried your suggestion but I came across  the `results` list creating its own independent  cost . I also  noticed that you didn’t  add the key names  of the data list and results list .

Comment: Ah the reason the timestamp didn’t t match was due to me using a perdelta  which uses a `datetime.now` which pretty much changed the time . sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [dict((key,d[key]) for d in data for key in d) for data in [[{list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]:{'timestamp':results[index//len(results)][list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]]['timestamp'],'cost':5}} if flag else {list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]:{'timestamp':results[index//len(results)][list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]]['timestamp'],'cost':results[index//len(results)][list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]]['cost']}} for index,flag in enumerate(flags)][f_i:f_i+len(results[0])] for f_i in range(0, len([{list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]:{'timestamp':results[index//len(results)][list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]]['timestamp'],'cost':5}} if flag else {list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]:{'timestamp':results[index//len(results)][list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]]['timestamp'],'cost':results[index//len(results)][list(results[index//len(results)].keys())[index%3]]['cost']}} for index,flag in enumerate(flags)]), len(results[0]))]]
```